# wglUseFontBitmaps is not drawing on screen

Tags: c#, opengl, arcgis

I've posted this question in gis.stackexchange earlier but I'm not sure if that was in fact the right place to post it, since this is more of a coding/technical question.  I'm attempting to draw a character in 3D Space.  However, nothing seems to place the character on the screen.

Below is what I'm attempting to do in code:  Anyone have any ideas?  I'm beyond lost at this point and will admit that I know next to nothing about openGL

```
double outX = 0;
double outY = 0;
double outZ = 0;

//This allows ArcGlobe to convert a lat lon into a 3D Coordinate system between -1 and 1
myGlobeViewUtil.GeographictoGeocentric(0 ,0 ,0 , out outX , out outY , out outZ);

Font font = new Font("Courier New" , 32.0f , FontStyle.Bold);
uint dbase = GL.genLists(256);
wglUseFontBitmaps(this.Handle, 32, 256 , dbase);

GL.glLoadIdentity();
GL.glTranslatef(0.0f , 0.0f , -1.0f);

GL.glColor3f(1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f);
GL.glRasterPos3d(geoX , geoY , geoZ);
GLPrint("TEST");



private void GLPrint(string inText)
{
  GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_LIST_BIT);
  GL.glListBase(dbase -32);
  GL.glCallLists(text.length , GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT , text);
  GL.glPopattrib();
}
```

EDIT: Due to pre-existing requirements I must use CsGL
http://csgl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally now it works!

```
public class OurView : OpenGLControl
{
    readonly GDITextureFont _myGDITextureFont = new GDITextureFont(new Font("Courier New", 32.0f, FontStyle.Bold));

    public override void glDraw()
    {
        OpenGL.glClear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer

        OpenGL.glLoadIdentity();
        OpenGL.glTranslated(0, 0, -1000); // !!!
        OpenGL.glRotated(35, 1, 1.2, 0.2);
        OpenGL.glScaled(2, 2, 2);

        OpenGL.glPushMatrix();
        OpenGL.glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        OpenGL.glTranslated(-20, -10, 100);

        _myGDITextureFont.DrawString("Working!");
        OpenGL.glPopMatrix();

    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        Size s = Size;
        double aspect_ratio = (double)s.Width / (double)s.Height;

        OpenGL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        OpenGL.glLoadIdentity();

        // special frustum, to have nice font display
        OpenGL.glFrustum(-s.Width, s.Width, -s.Height, s.Height, 700, 1300);

        OpenGL.glMatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        OpenGL.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}
```

Complete working example: http://cl.ly/2Z2m0A2v2U3p1j1m1p00

Comment: I can only use csGL...do not have access to OpenTK

Comment: @PSU: It doesn't matter.  Since both use the OpenGL API, what you learn from reading one example can be directly used in the other.  (At a glance, the difference is that OpenTK replaces the `gl` prefix on function names with the `GL.` namespace, while csGL retains the `gl` prefix and adds a namespace.)

Comment: @Skomski: Bitmap fonts are not geometrically transformed. glRasterPos goes through modelview and projection matrix and the viewport, but the result is just the offset position in the window where the bitmaps are drawn without further transformation. To get fonts that can be placed in the scene you must use either outline fonts, or texture mapped fonts.

Comment: @Skomski

OK, I'm trying the following:
GL.glTranslated(myX , myY, myZ);
myFont.DrawString("TEST");

But it says object reference not set to an instance

Stack Trace:
at CsGL.OpenGL.DisplayList.get_Base()
at CsGL.OpenGL.GDITextureFont.Push()
at CsGL.OpenGL.GDITextureFont.DrawString(String)

Comment: Works in my sandbox app, just need to integrate!

Comment: Suggestions if I'm using a 3rd party control?  C# doesn't allow for the multiple inheritance so I'm not sure

Comment: @PSU OpenGLControl is only a simple OpenGLContext in a Control. So look at the sourcecode and integrate the context directly or your 3rd party control create a openglcontext?

Comment: @Skomski any idea why the myGDITextureFont texture would be null?

Comment: @PSU cant really give an advise without any code etc. and not really a opengl expert. step through your code with debugger and isolate your problem (texture from beginning null etc) - maybe open a new question (we not should do this all in one comment thread)

Comment: @PSU When you find my answer useful I would appreciate the bounty :D